# Correct use of QDomElement::removeAttributeNS()?

Tags: c++, qt

What is the correct use of [QDomElement::removeAttributeNS()](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qdomelement.html#removeAttributeNS)?

Given this (incomplete) example input XML

```xml
<node xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="{company URL}"/>
```

How can I remove attribute `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`?

I have tried

```cpp
QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
root.removeAttributeNS("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation");
```

And I have tried

```cpp
QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
root.removeAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation");
```

Both to no avail.

I suppose I find the Qt documentation regarding the `nsURI` parameter confusing.

I have tried [QDomElement::removeAttribute()](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qdomelement.html#removeAttribute) passing in "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" as its only parameter and that works.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `removeAttributeNS()`?

Comment: When setting the `QDomDocument` content, did you select namespace processing?

Comment: @Ngoc No, as it turns out. The document is actually loaded in a framework, so I had to go deeper than just my app. I fudged the framework code to your suggestion and now it works. Now I have to work out if I should fix the framework or just read the attribute "flat" in my module. Entirely my problem. Fancy turning your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn namespace processing on when setting content for the `QDomDocument`.

Some overloads of [`QDomDocument::setContent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html#setContent) don't have this option and don't perform any namespace processing.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thanks!